# HTML5/CSS3 Scrollable Data Table

Tags: jquery, html, css

Guys I've been searching but I'm just after a simple, ground up design for an HTML5/CSS3/JQuery data table that has the following properties:

1) Sits inside an absolute DIV which has top,right,left,bottom attributes set so must scale to fit its parent.

2) Has horizontally resizable column headers.

3) Has a horizontal scroll that scrolls the column headers and data table.

4) Has a vertical scroll that scrolls only the data table.

I'd prefer not to use any frameworks other than JQuery but if you think it's easier then I'll try it.

Thanks guys.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm looking for suggestions on how I make a datatable with the above properties. Should I include a jsfiddle attempt?

Comment: Yes, you're required to show an attempt. Please see the [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) pages rather than leaving snarky comments directed at individuals.

Comment: I think you need to read the help as it seems you never have. 

First line: "Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers". Meaning freelancers use this too.

Second line: "We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them" meaning code is not essential.

Again my snarky comment that you deleted still stands: @Codenoir's answer is vastly more helpful than yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - get a misconception out of your head.  "Data table" and "simple" are mutually exclusive terms.

Second - jQuery is a library, but not a UI framework.

Third - I've had a lot of success with Kendo UI.  The Javascript core is open-source.  The Grid control may support absolute positioning but the scaling might be a stretch (if you want it to refresh on its own after the first time it renders).  You must have a decent command of Javascript to make it work, or don't waste your time.

[Grid demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index)

[Core download](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui/open-source-core)

I don't work for Telerik.  YMMV.